# UIButton corner radius on high resolution screens

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, swift2

I'm trying to create a circular UIButton in Swift. 
The button is 112px width and height and the code below works well in devices with at most, 4-inches screen.

```
button.layer.masksToBounds = false;
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.height/2;
button.clipsToBounds = true;
```

With bigger screens the button turns like this:

[image: Unexpected corner radius]

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can I get the screen scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust the `cornerRadius` after Auto Layout has sized your button.  Do this in an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.height/2
}
```